# Use radio button to expand or collapse expansion tile card flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use the radio button within the expansion tile card to expand and collapse the expansion card as well. I know the expansion card does that and I have already implemented that but I want to make the radio button have that functionality too. Can this be possible? and if yes please how can I do that?

**Below is an excerpt of my code**

```
        ExpansionTileCard(
        expandedTextColor: Colors.red,
        key: expansionKey,
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => buildExpansionToggle(),
          child: Radio(
            toggleable: true,
            activeColor: Color(
              0xFF000000,
            ),
            value: widget.groupValue,
            groupValue: widget.selectedRadio,
            onChanged: (value) {
              widget.onChanged(value);
            },
          ),
        ),
       ),


     buildExpansionToggle() {

   }
```

Comment: Sorry not getting, can you include two images of different state you are try to archive

Comment: could add the cod inside buildExpansionToggle?

Answer (score 1):

**So this is how I solved it**

Using the groupValue and the expansion key, I was able to call toggleExpansion method on it based on a condition.

```
        if (value == widget.groupValue) {
          expansionKey.currentState!.toggleExpansion();
        } else {
          expansionKey.currentState!.toggleExpansion();
        }
```